# Javascript add onclick event in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick

How do I add onclick events to elements in a loop? I have tried it like this.

```
            var c = "#FFFFFF"
            for(var i=0; i<_data.length; i++){
                c = c == "#FFFFFF" ? "#D8D8D8" : "#FFFFFF";

                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount++);
                row.style.backgroundColor = c;
                row.onclick = function(){
                    clickEvent(_data[i][0]);
                }

                newColl(row,i,0,_data[i][1]); //Name
                newColl(row,i,1,_data[i][2]); //Surname
                newColl(row,i,2,_data[i][3]); //Time working

                newColl(row,i,3,""); //TO-DO: Started at
                newColl(row,i,4,""); //TO-DO: Walked home
                newColl(row,i,5,""); //TO-DO: Took lunch
            }
```

I know that don't work, and I know why. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT DO THAT!!!!!. This is the exact reason why **Event Delegation** exists. Just attach **ONE click event** to the parent of the elements you are looping through and they should automatically dispatch click events when clicked.

[click here for an explanation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, since I wouldn't be able to get the ID from the rows.

Comment: the event object has all the properties of the object that dispatched the click event..including the ID...just do ***e.target.id***

Comment: I can't get that to work :/ I tried with setAttribute and ID. But all I get is null, and with the method of using class name, i get an empty string.

Comment: Can you put a stripped down version of your code in jsfiddle and share it, i might be able to help if i see how your html markup is structured. Are you creating the rows dynamically in JS?

Comment: I'm currently trying to. But my stripped down code won't run there.